# Chrome TD height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I've got a problem on beta.ovoweb.net ; the td (below the tabs, little grey line) isn't visible in Chrome. It is in Firefox. How can I fix this Chrome problem?

Answer (score 1):

The content of the td has zero height. Put content inside of it that has height.

Answer (score 1):

Because Chrome ignores blank area.

Try

```
<div id="ovoSubmenuContent">&nbsp;</div>
```

or

```
<td colspan="2" height="5">
   <div id="ovoSubmenuContent"></div>
</td>
```